# Optimize the trimming function

Tags: c++

There is the `void TrimRight( char *s )` function, which has a very long s-style string as an argument. A passed string consists of a lot of white spaces after a last word and, also, throughout its length. It is required that the function is to trim excess white spaces at the right.

I suggested an implementation looking like this:

```
void TrimRight(char *str) {
    char *space_pos{};  // last space position
    auto iterator{str}; // string iterator
    while (*iterator != '\0') {
      if (*iterator == ' ') { // save first space
        if (!space_pos) {
          space_pos = iterator;
        }
      } else {
        space_pos = nullptr;
      }
      ++iterator;
    }
    if (space_pos) { // if the string does not end with alpha
      *space_pos = '\0';
    }   
}
```

It works pretty well but `N` memory accesses seems excess, since the task given to me points out that a string is very long and contains many white spaces. Therefore, the question have been raised: Is there a way to refine the function in order to decrease a number of memory accesses?

Comment: With a C-string, you can't really do better than N accesses because you will always have to look for the `\0` string terminator sentinel.  However you *could* do better (namely by starting at the right side of the string) if you change the function to accept a `length` parameter.

Comment: You could rewrite it a bit so that when you find a space you scan forward looking for the first non-space, rather than always looping around and checking the two conditions. (`space_pos = iterator; while (*++iterator != ' ') { }`, and move the `++iterator` up into the else body with `space_pos = nullptr;`.) This would help the optimizer a bit but you're still memory bound to those N characters.

Comment: I'd use  `#include <cctype> std::isspace()`

Comment: @MatG Good catch. I didn't think about the wording and only looked at OP:s code. I added a note about _whitespaces_ to my answer.

Comment: The question text talks about trimming whitespace, the code trims only space. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never know where you may find a non-space character so you do have to look through the whole string.

You could do it with a lot less comparisons though.

Example:

```
void TrimRight(char *iterator) {
    for(;; ++iterator) {
        // Loop for as long as the string has not ended and non-space chars are
        // found.
        for(;*iterator != ' '; ++iterator) {
            // Return if the end of the string is found. If the end of the string
            // is found here, it did not end with spaces.
            if(*iterator == '\0') return;
        }

        // A space position is found, store it.
        char* space_pos = iterator;

        // Loop for as long as there are spaces.
        do ++iterator; while(*iterator == ' ');

        // Return if the end of the string is found. If the end of the string
        // is found at this stage, it ended with spaces so trim the string.
        if(*iterator == '\0') {
            *space_pos = '\0';
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You mention *whitespaces* in your text but you only test for *spaces*. If you really need to trim away all trailing *whitespaces*, replace the comparisons with `' '` above with [`std::isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) tests, like this:

```
for(;!std::isspace(*iterator); ++iterator) {
```

and

```
do ++iterator; while(std::isspace(*iterator));
```

Comment: This will convert `"Hello    world"` into `"Hello"`. It needs to trim only trailing spaces, not the last set of spaces

Comment: @Kevin Oh snap :-) Thanks - fixed it.